# Single text file: Compare the first n characters of each line and the next. If they are equal print the longer of the two in output file

Tags: ubuntu, text-processing, scripting

I am using the Ubuntu bash.
My file contains paths from a filesystem.

E.g.

```
C:\users\username\subfolder\thisismyfile.txt
C:\users\username\subfolder\thisismyfileplusadate.txt
C:\users\username\subfolder2\thisismyfileplusname.txt
C:\users\username\subfolder3\thisismyfile.txt
```

What I want to do:

Compare each start of each line with the start of the next line.

E.g.

First n characters of line 1 first n characters of the following line.
If this substring is identical I want to compare the complete length of the two lines and the longer path of the two should be printed to an output file concatenated with the length of that longer path.

So for my example above:

```
C:\users\username\subfolder\thisismyfile.txt
C:\users\username\subfolder\thisismyfileplusadate.txt
```

The first n characters, let's say 28 so "C:\users\username\subfolder\" would be compared. They are identical. Next I want to compare the length of the lines to each other. Line 1 would be 44 characters and line 2 53.

So I want to print line 1 to an output file and concatenate "length: 53" to the string (or the beginning of the line)

How would I go about this?

Comment: Do you need to compare *pairs* of lines (1 against 2, 3 against 4 and so on) or every line against the next (1 against 2, 2 against 3, ...)?

Comment: Thank you for your question. Every line against the next. So n to n+1, n+1 to n+2, n2 to n+3 and so on.

Comment: Case sensitive?

Comment: Not really. All the paths are similar enough so lower-/uppercase is not relevant

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash 

file_len=$(wc -l afile.txt | awk {'print $1'});
let "flen = $file_len-1";
nth=28;
for i in $(seq 1 $flen); do {
        li_cut="";
        ly_cut="";
        let "y = $i +1";
        line_i=$(sed -n "$i"p afile.txt);
        len_i=$(echo $line_i | wc -m)
        li_cut="${line_i:0:$nth}";
        line_y=$(sed -n "$y"p afile.txt);
        len_y=$(echo $line_y | wc -m)
        ly_cut="${line_y:0:$nth}";

        if [ "$li_cut" == "$ly_cut" ]; then {
                if [ $len_i -gt  $len_y ]; then {
                        echo "$line_i [ $len_i ];"
                } fi
                if [ $len_y -ge $len_i ]; then  {
                        echo "$line_y [ $len_y ]";
                } fi;
        } fi;
} done
```

something like this ?
Won't be that good with huge txts and might be probably coded in some prettier forms.

Edit: it might be useful to use a sort|uniq in the end, given that:
if line n+1 > n and line n+1 > n+2 you'll get a 'repeated' n+1

Answer (score 0):

To print the content of the longer path alongside the length of that path:

```
awk -v n=28 '
  substr($0,1,n) == substr(last,1,n) {
    if(length($0) > length(last))
      printf("length: %d %s\n", length($0), $0);
    else
      printf("length: %d %s\n", length(last), last);
  }
  {last = $0}
' file
length: 53 C:\users\username\subfolder\thisismyfileplusadate.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I edited my original post. I want to print the content of the longer path alongside the length of that path.

Comment: @user358244 please see updated answer